# Нужно ли выделить запятыми оборот с «как» в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, как

> Тем самым художница добавляет в исторический портрет как в жанр
>   современные тенденции.

Answer (score 2):

Тем самым художница добавляет в исторический портрет **как в жанр** современные тенденции.

**Запятые не нужны**, оборот не обособляется, так как имеет значение "в качестве, считая, рассматривая" (здесь значение отождествления, а не сравнения).

**Розенталь**
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147
4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

3) если союз как имеет значение ‘в качестве’ или сравнительный оборот с союзом как характеризует предмет лишь с одной стороны: Богат, хорош собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених (П.); Итак, я вам советую как приятель быть осторожнее (Л.); Я говорю как литератор (М. Г.); Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры; Я сохраню это письмо как память;

Может быть, лучше сказать так: *Тем самым художница добавляет в жанр исторического портрета  современные тенденции.*

Comment: Исходная фраза плохо воспринимается как в письменном виде , так и на слух. Да и смысл туманный. Мне нравится вариант, предложенный  Sharon.